# jQuery .val() not setting the value of <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I would like to know why jQuery's `.val()`  function is not setting the value of the `<select>` control for me after I called replaceWith, but it is working otherwise.

Please [see here for a (not) working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qSYYc/).

```
<select><option>ABC</option><option>DEF</option></select>
<input type="button" onclick="ControlOff()" value="Turn Off Control" />
<input type="button" onclick="ControlOn()" value="Turn On Control" />
<input type="button" onclick="Test()" value="Value Setting Test" /> 
function ControlOff() {
    $('select').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<span class="select-type">' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
    });
}

function ControlOn() {
    $('.select-type').each(function () {
        var selected = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<select><option>ABC</option><option>DEF</option></select>');
        $(this).val(selected);
    });
}

function Test() {
    $('select').val('DEF');
}
```

Comment: `but is it ok just to refer people to my question to jsFiddle` - not only is it ok, it's super awsome!

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. I believe you'll want to set the `value` parameter of the `option` items, though like `<option value='abc'>abc</option>`

Comment: +1 on setting the value. Also, it works in FF15.0.1

Comment: No. It doesn't work on my latest FF and latest Chrome. Try setting the drop down to DEF then click Control Off, and then click Control On. While that should set the select to DEF but it won't.

Comment: it works for me too (chrome 22).

Comment: Why are you replacing? Just show and hide the thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `ControlOn` you have an `each` which is looping over `.select-type` elements which are `span`'s and spans cannot be set with the `val` method:

You can fix this by changing the method to this:

```
function ControlOn() {
    $('.select-type').each(function () {
        var selected = $(this).text();
        var $select = $('<select><option>ABC</option><option>DEF</option></select>');
        $(this).replaceWith($select)
        $select.val(selected);
    });
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qSYYc/4/

Comment: Well that works but I am setting $(this), not ALL the `<select>`. Think about when I have more than one `<select>` with different values, I can't use your code. My question is $(this) has already been replaced by `<select>`, isn't $(this) now `<select>`? And of course `<select>` has val to be set.

Comment: @user1589188 - I totally see your point, its my bad as you were using the somewhat wide-reaching `$('select')` selector elsewhere in your example. I'll look again.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats the way to do it! So its true that $(this) is not being updated after calling replaceWith. Weird! You see if you call `alert($(this).text())` even after calling replaceWith, you're still getting the text in the span!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `$(this)` in `$(this).val(selected)` refers to the **removed** `<span>` element, not your new element. You need to replace it with:

```
$('select').val(selected);
```

to grab the previously inserted **new** element.

Also, your code is unecessarily complex, this does the same thing, but simpler:

```
function ControlOn() {
    $selectText = $('.select-type');
    var selected = $selectText.text();
    $selectText.replaceWith('<select><option>ABC</option><option>DEF</option></select>');
    $('select').val(selected); // Use an id instead to match: #my-select-id
}
```

Make sure to give the `<select>` element an ID, otherwise it's going to mess up once you introduce a new `<select>` element somewhere else on the page.

[See here for a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q4wy/)

Comment: Thanks for your input and +1 for pointing out $(this) is not being updated to the new control after calling replaceWith. But my code is not complex, I had that because thats for more than one `<select>`. So again, your code is not generalized for more than one `<select>` but only works when there is one single `<select>`

Comment: @user1589188 Sure, but you never said that there are multiple. But if there are, you would have changed *all* `<select>`s ;) Please provide more context then (in your original question) so I can better reflect your situation in my code.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my code. Like I said, my code is generalized to cope with multiple `<select>`. Just add more `<select>` to the HTML and DONT change my code, you can see my code works on all of them. I just removed multiple `<select>` from the HTML part, just to make the example smaller. But thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: @user1589188 I understand that. What I meant is, that it doesn't say so in the question, which is why you have to expect that some will point that simplification out to you. It was just meant to be an advice for future questions ;)

Comment: Yes I see your point. I will try to further simplify my code or state it clearly next time. I copied my code directly this time for I fear that I might have done something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

set value of options will solve your problem. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSYYc/5/)

```
<select><option value='ABC'>ABC</option><option value="DEF">DEF</option></select>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Try setting the drop down to DEF then click Control Off, and then click Control On. You dont see the drop down select DEF, no?

Comment: This is irrelevant, if a `value` attribute is omitted, the value inherits from the text.

Comment: @Jamiec what if value and text are different? in that case your suggestion will fail.

Comment: But, crucially, in the OP question they *are* the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ControlOn() {
    $('.select-type').each(function () {
        var selected = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith($('<select><option>ABC</option><option>DEF</option></select>').val(selected));
    });
}
```

Rewrite your code like above, it would work!

The element referenced by `this` won't change to the select element you just created, it will always be the `span` element inside the scope of that function. Therefore you should set the value to the newly created `select` instead of the invariant `$(this)`!

Comment: Yes I just realized that. But thats just weird to me. When will $(this) be updated??? I wonder whats happening behind replaceWith

Comment: `this` is the reference to the object to which the function was bounded, because of its nature, it can never be reassigned. If you're familiar with java/c++, you would understand the rationale.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you to use "disabled" attribute to turn select on and off, it, won't mess up the .val() functionality

```
function ControlOff() {
    $("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

function ControlOn() {
    $("select").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I want to achieve.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? Because to have <select> tag with <span> tags inside is kinda nonsense (can contain only <option> and <optgroup> tags http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 ) and may behave differently on different browsers

Comment: No, I use replaceWith to replace `<select>` with `<span>`, not adding `<span>` inside `<select>`

Comment: Oops, sorry, my bad. I must be tired or something :-).